# Конвентирование OGG в WAV

Tags: python, wav, ogg

Пользуюсь двумя строками

```
data, samplerate = sf.read('audio1.ogg')
sf.write('audio1.wav', data, samplerate)
```

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
 File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", 
line 372, in read
   with SoundFile(file, 'r', samplerate, channels,
 File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", 
line 740, in __init__
 self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
 File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", 
line 1264, in _open
   _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
 File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", 
line 1455, in _error_check
   raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'audio1.ogg': System error.
```

В чём ошибка? Перерыл кучу источников по этой проблеме, ничего толкового не нашёл

Comment: Что за ```sf```? Какой модуль используете? Больше информации!

Comment: Попробуйте проложить полный путь к файлам

Comment: Путь полный указывал.
Модуль - speech_recognition